# What is "controller.controllers" in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

What is "controller.controllers" in Ember.js ?

It seems that

```
this.getPath("controller.controllers")
```

in the view returns App.router. 
It's very usefull but I'd like to understand what I'm doing :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `initialize` on your `Ember.Application`, all controllers are instantiated and set on the router. The controller in turn also gets some properties injected, as implemented [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-application/lib/system/application.js#L216-232). As you can see, the `controllers` property is a reference to the router.

```js
Ember.Application.registerInjection({
  name: 'controllers',
  injection: function(app, router, property) {
    if (!/^[A-Z].*Controller$/.test(property)) { return; }

    var name = property.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + property.substr(1),
        controller = app[property].create();

    router.set(name, controller);

    controller.setProperties({
      target: router,
      controllers: router,
      namespace: app
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But it's pretty confusing. Why its called **controllers** if it is **router**?

Comment: Because it's an array of controllers that a specific controller has access to via `needs`. (http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)